# Есть ли смысл глубоко изучать Swing?

Tags: java, swing

Есть ли смысл глубоко изучать Swing? Он сейчас применяется при создании приложений или используются другие фрейворки. Я просто задаю этот вопрос, посмотрев вакансии Java-разработчиков и требования указанные. Там что-то не так часто про него пишется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing в меру востребован. Есть проекты полностью написанные на Swing. Но даже если основной проект пишется не на нем, то довольно часто появляется необходимость в создании каких-то утилит для облегчения работы над проектом - тут Swing тоже может пригодится, если требуется что-то большее чем Command Line утилита. И самое главное, я не думаю, что изучение Swing отнимет у Вас слишком много времени.

Мне, например, знание Swing помогло без труда освоить GWT. И вообще Swing и весь JFC лично мне очень нравится.

P.S. На Swing можно реализовать интерфейс любой сложности, главное достаточно хорошо знать его возможности.

Comment: В этом ответе слово `Swing` можно заменить на название многих других гуёв. Один нормально изучил -- с другими уже легче. Должен ли быть swing первым -- вопрос сложный, зависящий от многих сопутствующих факторов. Но если начал изучать его -- лучше изучить нормально, с другими, повторяю, будет проще.

Answer (score 1):

для SE десктоп приложений swing изучить стоит. тем более после понятия архитектуры построения интефейса на swing делать интерфейсы на qt,gtk и других тулкитах гораздо проще так как понятно как работать с "динамическим" расположением виджетов.